# How can I overlay two pictures in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to place two pictures at the same place on the webpage - to overlay each other (later on I'll add some webkit animations for them to move in two different directions, but the startpoint should be the same). I have the following css layout (here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfyacy25/7/)). The CSS here looks like this:

```
.intro{
    background-color: #b0e0e6;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 5px;
}
.intro:before,.intro:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.intro:after {
    clear: both;
}
.image{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #aaaae6;
    float: left;
}
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;

}
.text{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    float: left;
}
```

as you can see in the fiddle, now two pictures are one below the other, so I've decided to modify the css and add this:

```
img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 25%;      
}
```

but that causes the  not visible at all... How can I preserve the size of that div and just put two images directly in it?

Comment: Set display: none; You can play with hidden/show (jquery)

Comment: z-index? and absolute positioning!

Comment: To overlay image you need absolute positioning. However, if you do that the `image` div will collapse as the images will be taken out of the flow. You would need to give that dive some width & height and the position the images accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

As a starting point for consideration: in CSS3, a single element can have [multiple, stacked `background` images](https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/).  Example:

```
.my-container {
  background:
    url(grid.png),
    url(building.jpg)
}
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/eDJpi).

In CSS2 and below, you can use `z-index`, `absolute`, `width`, and `height` etc.